# Trigger an iOS Visual Studio Cordova build form the command line

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I can successfully run a build of the Android app from the command line.

For iOS the build fails using this command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.com" "<Solution>.sln" /rebuild "Distribution|iOS" /project "<projectName>" /projectconfig "Distribution|iOS"
```

This is the error:

> 1>MSBUILD : cordova-build error BLD301: Error : BLD00301 : A remote
>   iOS build agent has not been configured. Configure one in Tools >
>   Options > Tools for Apache Cordova > Remote Agent Configuration. For
>   details and alternatives see
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=511904

I have the remote server configured in visual studio but obviously this is not being picked up. Is there a way to feed this configuration into the batch build?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To build your Cordova iOS project under MSBuild, with help of Cordova Tools for Visual Studio. You need to add a property to your MSBuild named `iOSRemoteBuildServer`. The build command line should looks like this, I am using debug build as an example:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin\msbuild.exe"
    /p:Configuration=Debug
    /p:LangName=en-US
    /p:Platform=iOS
    /p:DebuggerFlavor=iOSRemoteDevice
    /p:iOSRemoteBuildServer=http://192.168.0.123:3000
```

You will find your IPA output at `bin\iOS\Debug\` folder.

If MSBuild failed with missing environment variables, the followings should help (assume you are on Cordova Tools CTP3.1 and Node.js 64-bit):

```
SET MDAVsixDir=%VS120COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\EXTENSIONS\IIC52DPN.UDK
SET NodeJsDir=C:\Program Files\nodejs\
SET NpmInstallDir=%APPDATA%\npm
```

To set a security PIN for retrieving the client certificate, you can use MSBuild property `iOSRemoteBuildSecurityPIN` but I have not tested this property yet.

Comment: Where do you add these commands? In Visual Studio command prompt?

Comment: Yes, just before you run msbuild to build your Cordova project in Command Prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you need to start the remote agent on your Mac machine, get the IP/host, the port and the pin and configure it using Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova in VS, before you can initiate the build. Visual studio wouldn't start the remote server for you.

The process to setup the remote agent is explained at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771551.aspx.

Comment: I've got all that covered, as I can successfully build it from Visual Studio. The problem is getting the build to run from the command line.

Comment: When comparing the output from visual studio and the command line I can see that the remote agent server and port configuration values are not available for the command line run.

Comment: Sorry, VS doesn't support building iOS on the remote agent through command line.